# How to show image/videos when table cell will expand?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have created table in which i want to expand cell when click on '+' button, and add image and videos in that. At time it need to increase the particular cell hight and then show the videos and '+' sign will convert into '-'.

[image]

right now i added code to expand the cell as follows

```
-(void)cellButtonOneSelected
{
    // Deselect cell
[safetChecklistsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath1 animated:TRUE];

// Toggle 'selected' state
BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:selectedIndexPath1];

// Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
[selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:selectedIndexPath1];    

// This is where magic happens...
[safetChecklistsTableView beginUpdates];
[safetChecklistsTableView endUpdates];
}
```

Now how to show/add videos or images in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the videos and images in a uiview and add them to your cell like if the height of cell is 50, add them on 51. and write

```
yourView.hidden=YES; 
yourView.tag=@"your Tag"
```

When this add button is pressed, call the following loop:

```
for (int section = 0, sectionCount = _iTableView.numberOfSections; section < sectionCount; ++section) {
        for (int row = 0, rowCount = [_iTableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row < rowCount; ++row) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [_iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
            UIView *view=(UIView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:@"Your Tag"];
            view.hidden=NO;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: You should atleast give a +1 for the hard work of answerer...and also accept your answer as the answer..if you think that is right..

Answer (score 0):

add the following code in cell 'cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

```
 if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath])
    {
        [cellButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:plusImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cellSubLabel.text=@"Close";

      if (indexPath==selectedIndexPath) {
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        imageView.frame = (CGRect){170,80,130,80};
        [tableCell addSubview:imageView];
     }
   }
    else
    {
        [cellButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:minusImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    }
```